# ¿como decifrar la cadena de conexion en el config?

Tags: c#, .net, app.config

Tengo una app windows forms con .net framework 4.0. Encripté la cadena de conexion en el config de la manera que está aquí descrita: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/795135/encrypt-connectionstring-in-web-config

Me funciona genial en mi pc.

Sin embargo cuando instalo la app en el cliente, no funciona y me aparace el siguiente error en log:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error al descifrar
> utilizando el proveedor 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Mensaje
> de error desde el proveedor: No pudo abrirse el contenedor de claves
> RSA.

¿Cómo podría resolver ese error?

Comment: Hola! Procura siempre incluir el código relevante. En este caso, el que cifra y descifra la cadena de conexión. Si ese enlace cambia, se acaba el sitio o cambian las URL, tu pregunta ya no será útil para otros con el mismo problema. De paso, hace más fácil y rápido el que podamos ayudarte aquí

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que la aplicación aspnet_regis utilice para encriptar el certificado de la máquina, por eso no puedes desencriptarlo desde otro ordenador.

Puede que necesites encriptar la cadena de conexión además desde el ordenador de producción y seleccionar una u otra cadena dependiendo del entorno.

Quizá te ayude la documentación de la aplicación:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)